# Python : comparing lines of a file with keys of a dictionary in the memory

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to compare values of key "rrname" in a json format file ,jadata dic (Each line is a dictionary) with keys of dictionary d which is already loaded in memory.

Here is my code:
    import simplejson

```
ap = '/data/data/2014/A.1/ap.txt'
ddb = '/data/data/2014/A.1/test'


d={}
f = open(ap,'r')
g = open(ddb,'r')

for line in f:
    domain,bl_date= line.split('|')
    d[domain]=bl_date

for line in g:
    line=line.strip('')
    try:
        jdata = simplejson.loads(line)
        if jdata.get('rrname') == d.keys():
            print rrname
    except:
        raise
```

here is my ddb file :

```
{"rrname": "bba186684.alshamil.net.ae.", "time_last": 1389295255, "time_first": 1389241418,  }
{"rrname": "bba186686.alshamil.net.ae.", "time_last": 1390910891, "time_first": 1390910891}
{"rrname": "0001ewm.rcomhost.com", "time_last": 1390147425, "time_first": 1390124988}
```

here is ap file:

```
0001elk.rcomhost.com|1391726703
0001ewm.rcomhost.com|1393472522
0001qz6.wcomhost.com|1399977648
```

when I run this code, it cannot find the similarities, although there is. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: can you paste `apwg2014.txt` content ?

Comment: @levi sure , just editted

Comment: Should `if jdata.get('rrname') == d.keys()` be `if jdata.get('rrname') in d.keys()`?  Should `print rrname` be `print jdata.get('rrname')`?

Comment: @KevinS haha my stupid mistake! thanks- it is been resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jdata.get('rrname') == d.keys()
```

will always fail -- the single entry on the left of the `==` won't equal **all** entries on the right as you're asking.

Rather, check whether:

```
jdata.get('rrname') in d
```

The `in` operator looks for the left side to be **contained** in the right side.  It's important for performance to use `d`, **not** `d.keys()`, as the right side, since checking for containment in a dictionary is much faster than checking in a list (as `.keys` would be in Python 2, which I guess is what you're using, even though you don't tell us!, based on the syntax for that `print`:-).